# This regex matches in BBEdit and regex.com, but not on iOS - why?

Tags: ios, regex

I am trying to "highlight" references to law statutes in some text I'm displaying.  These references are of the form `<number>-<number>-<number>(char)(char)`, where:

- "number" may be whole numbers `18` or decimal numbers `12.5`;
- the parenthetical terms are entirely optional: zero or one or more;
- if a parenthetical term does exist, there may or may not be a space between the last number and the first parenthesis, as in `18-1.3-401(8)(g)` or `18-3-402 (2)`.

I am using the regex

`((\d+(\.\d+)*-){2}(\d+(\.\d+)*))( ?(\([0-9a-zA-Z]+\))*)`

to find the ranges of these strings and then highlight them in my text.  This expression works perfectly, 100% of the time, in all of the cases I've tried (dozens), in BBEdit, and on regex101.com and regexr.com.

However, when I use that exact same expression in my code, on iOS 12.2, it is extremely hit-or-miss as to whether a string matching the regex is actually found. So hit-or-miss, in fact, that a string of the exact same form of two other matches in a specific bit of text is NOT found.  E.g., in this one paragraph I have, there are five instances of `xxx-x-xxx`; the first and the last are matched, but the middle three are not matched.  This makes no sense to me.

I'm using the `String` method `func range(of:options:range:locale:)` with options of `.regularExpression` (and `nil` locale) to do the matching.  I see that iOS uses ICU-compatible regexes, whereas these other tools use PCRE (I think).  But, from what I can tell, my expression should be compatible and valid for my case with the ICU parsing.  But, something is definitely different, and I cannot figure out what it is.

Anyone?  (I'm going to give `NSRegularExpression` a go and see if it behaves differently, but I'd still like to figure out what's going on here.)

Comment: Show actual code that fully demonstrates your issue, including sample input.

Comment: I suspect there might be a unpredictable backtracking issue. Try both of these regex. The worst that could happen is it won't work either.  `((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?-){2}(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))((?:[ ]?\([0-9a-zA-Z]+\))*)` or `((?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?-){2}(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?))((?:[ ]?\([0-9a-zA-Z]+\))*)`